# Atividade com dois Layouts e EditText focusable

Tags: android

A minha app só possui uma actividade mas com dois Layouts.

A comutação entre os dois Layouts é feita através de um Button que existe em cada um dos Layouts.

No Layout 1 existe um `EditText` do tipo *numérico* e no Layout 2 existe outro `EditText` mas do tipo *texto*.

Os dois EditTexts tem a propriedade focusable activa, mas quando faço a comutação entre os Layouts o tipo de teclado não é alterado automaticamente, ou seja, para alterar o tipo de teclado tenho de dar um click no EditText desse Layout.

Já tentei no condigo java inserir a linha `edittext2.setFocusable(true)` mas não funciona.

Comment: Como você está a fazer a comutação entre *layouts*? Poste o código da activity.

Comment: Olá ramaral! Estou a fazer a comutação através do evento click dos Buttons. Contudo, obrigado pela atenção, mas já encontrei a solução:  edittext2.requestFocus();

Answer (score 1):

Fácil, muito fácil:

```
edittext2.requestFocus();
```

Aqui fica o código completo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button botao1;
    Button botao2;
    EditText edittext1;
    EditText edittext2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Layout_1();
    }

    public void Layout_1() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_1);
        botao1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edittext1.requestFocus();
        botao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Layout_2();
            }
        });

    }

    public void Layout_2() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
        botao2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edittext2.requestFocus();
        botao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Layout_1();
            }
        });
    }
}
```